# How to read and create this type of TCPDUMP

Tags: traffic-shaping, tcpdump

I am having an issue with my tcpdump command i have created.
Chances are its wrong. 
What i want to do is this:
Run this command:

```
tc qdisc add dev eth0 root tbf rate 6kbit latency 50ms burst 1540
```

run this tcpdump:

```
sudo tcpdump host wiki and wiki2 -c5 -vvv -w dump
```

Then alter the tc command to this and run it:

```
tc qdisc add dev eth0 root tbf rate 60kbit latency 50ms burst 1540
```

and run the same command:

```
sudo tcpdump host wiki and wiki2 -c5 -vvv -w dump
```

and dump the speed change.

What i am getting now shows nothing about this.
Can i get some help writing the appropriate tcpdump command?

thanks,
Pastelinux

Comment: Oh? Well adding host between the two works! Now how do i read the output to show me that the packets take longer once i shape one of the hosts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you're putting arguments after the filter expression. The expression should be last, e.g.

```
sudo tcpdump -c5 -vvv -w dump host wiki and wiki2
```

Second, "host wiki and wiki2" matches packets which contain **both** of the following:

- An IPv4 or IPv6 source or destination of "wiki"
- An IPv4 or IPv6 source or destination of "wiki2"

That is, traffic directly between "wiki" and "wiki2". You might have better luck with something like this:

```
sudo tcpdump -c5 -vvv -w dump host wiki or host wiki2
```

Comment: Oh? Well adding host between the two works! Now how do i read the output to show me that the packets take longer once i shape one of the hosts?

Comment: I would open it in Wireshark, go to "Statistics→Conversation List→TCP (IPv4 & IPv6)" and look at the last two (bps) columns. However, my opinion is biased in that regard. If you want to solve the problem using only tcpdump you could probably get useful information using the "-ttttt" flag.

Comment: yeah i wish it was as easy as using wireshark. the outcomes of this will be installed in a python script that automatically creates the tcpdump after i shape one of the hosts.

Comment: Also, are you sure it wasn't changing the "and" to an "or" that fixed your problem? Does "tcpdump -d host wiki and wiki2" and "tcpdump -d host wiki and host wiki2" generate different output? If so there's a bug in libpcap on your system.

Comment: actually they show the exact thing.

Comment: sudo tcpdump -c5 -w dump host wiki or host wiki2
doesn't work, i don't know why i thought it did before. weird. could have sworn it did.

Comment: This is my script now: http://pastebin.com/1PZZhm68